# How do I render a jpg image using ARKit ARSKViewDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, arkit

I'd like to render a jpg image as a 2d rectangle floating in space. Using the SpriteKit example - how do I return a jpg image from the `ARSKViewDelegate`?

The demo returns a `SKLabelNode` - is there a Node class that would be appropriate for a jpg image that I would fetch from the network, maybe a `UIImage`?

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    // Create and configure a node for the anchor added to the view's session.
    let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "")
    labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    return labelNode;
}
```

Comment: SpriteKit (the "SK" in the APIs you've mentioned) is *all about* putting images on the screen. Have you looked at its [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit) at all?

Comment: Yup, I was looking at the docs but didn't see anything about an SKNode from a UI Image.  Hunting around stackoverflow I found the answer using an SKTexture and SKPriteNode

Comment: I’m curious how `SKSpriteNode` doesn’t stand out enough in that doc page... “A node that draws a rectangular texture, **image** or color.”

Comment: @rickseter Well I'm not familiar with 3d, graphics and sprite kit at all - meaning when I see the word "texture" I was uncertain if it would be something more heavy than just a simple image (since previously I associate that with 3d models).  Obviously it's a simple question - but I think it would be useful for people just starting out with sprite kit.  Keeping responses positive would help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`SCNPlane`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnplane) and assign a `UIImage` as content of that plane.

```
let imagePlane = SCNPlane(width: sceneView.bounds.width/6000, height: sceneView.bounds.height/6000)
imagePlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = //<-- UIImage here
imagePlane.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .constant
let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: imagePlane)
```

**UPDATE:** now I noticed that you're using SpriteKit. The code I shared is using SceneKit.

Comment: thanks for the answer - is it more efficient to use spritekit in this case vs scenekit?  Or, does it not really matter?

Comment: Well, I think it doesn't really matter but I don't have the knowledge to confirm that at 100%.

Comment: I presume its all Open GL - ES in the end - SpriteKit or SceneKit. Thats how you can do normal maps in Sprite Kit. SpriteKit nodes just always face the camera and camera perspective is reduced?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can use an `SKSpriteNode` from an `SKTexture`.  The only issue with that is I see in the logs warnings about degraded ar performance. `[Technique] World tracking performance is being affected by resource constraints [1]`

```
let url = URL(string: imageURL)
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check
let theImage = UIImage(data: data!)
let Texture = SKTexture(image: theImage!)
return SKSpriteNode(texture: Texture)
```